# Create, modify and display an instance of a component

Tags: angular, material-design, angular-material, angular-material2

using Angular2+, Material

I just can't find an answer for hours, so I'll give it a try here:

I'm working on a tab-layout. I can add new tabs dynamically, that's working. But instead of just displaying some "raw" data as content, I want it to be an entire component but with individual values

My approach right now:
- a button instantiates a new component object
- the components values are being modified
- the modified component is being added to an array
- then I iterate over the array it was put in
- for every component that was saved to the array: generate 1 tab
- now the problem: trying to fill the tabs content with the specific component

**in HTML:**

```
<mat-tab-group>  <mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" label={{tab.title}}> SHOW MODIFIED COMPONENT HERE </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>

...

<button mat-raised-button color="basic" (click)="updateUser()">Update</button>
```

**in TS:**

```
  tabs: any[] = [];

...

  updateUser() {
    const newUser = new UserdetailsComponent(new FormBuilder(), this.dataService);
    newUser.title = 'tester';
    newUser.emailFormControl.patchValue('JOHN@WAYNE.COM');
    this.tabs.push(newUser);
  }
...
```

**the UserdetailsComponent, which is to be intantiated, modified and displayed:**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-userdetails',
  templateUrl: './userdetails.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./userdetails.component.css'],
})
export class UserdetailsComponent implements OnInit {
  title = 'New User';

  ...

  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder, private dataService: DataService) {
    this.emailFormControl = new FormControl('', [
      Validators.required,
      Validators.email,
    ]);

...

    this.formGroup = formBuilder.group({
      'email': this.emailFormControl,
...
    });
  }
...
```

I don't get any errors, I can also load the titles from the components I pushed into tabs dynamically in the HTML. Changing the components properties (title and emailFormControl) works. But I need to display the entire component in the tabs content field, not only parts. Any ideas?